# Node webkit app not starting (app size 3.8gb)

Tags: windows, node.js, macos, express, node-webkit

i just ran into a problem with my [node webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) app using express framework.

Situation:

I successfully built the app with ~ 150mb, including some dummy data. I'm zipping the whole project and rename it to .nw according to the instructions readme. Everything is working fine.

BUT:

When adding the actual content to the app, the app size grows up to 3.8gb. It seems that my windows machine (4GB RAM / 32bit windows 7) can't start the app. I've waited almost an hour - several times, but still nothing happens - no error message, no hourglass cursor - just nothing.

Does anyone know of any limitation regarding node app size which could possibly cause this "misbehaviour"? It runs flawlessly on my mac with 8GB RAM, so i guess there's the rub...

If you could just help me, that'd be great,
thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This article should explain part of your problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier

The other part of your problem: Are you sure you need to load all 3.8GB of that application at once?  There are relatively few applications where that would be a hard requirement.  Is there a part of your application that you could refactor in order to have a much smaller portion in memory at any single time?

Comment: Was expecting something like that, so thank you!

The only remarkable files the app is holding are some videos. Since I'm not an expert yet, I'm not sure how to exclude them from the actual app.